# SELECT Top(1), aggregate function with Where clause

Tags: sql-server-2000, aggregate, where-clause

OK, I've googled and googled and still can't get this.

Effectively, in a table containing several hundred thosand rows, one column has a unique idendtifier (not a PK and not really unique, but hey) and another has numerical values.

The unique identifier (UI) is unique only within that table and is sort of incremental, in that the highest number signifies the most recent table entry.

Effectively, I need to break the rows down to relevant rows using a WHERE clause, then get the most recent UI of those rows together with the SUM of the values of those rows.

i.e.  if UI are 1, 3, 5, 7, 10 and the corresponding values for the aggregate function are 100, 300, 500, 700 and 1000, what I need to have as query result is UI 10, Sum 2600.

DB is SQL2000

How do I acheive this?

Comment: I don't understand your question... Could you elaborate a bit more as to what the table actually looks like and what data you want pulled??

Comment: It sounds like [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=greatest-n-per-group) may lead to something relevant ..

Comment: @John, ok, I'll try.  One column in the table records a currency amount relating to a financial transaction.  Another column records financial values.  All transactions are recorded in the same table, and every transaction is given a reference number, which increments for every financial transaction recorded.  So you may have ref 1, value 1000, description current account and the following row might be ref 1, value -1000, description savings account.  After several of these, a report is needed.  The idea is to sum values based on criteria and get the last ref no to ascertain a cut off point

Comment: @John to try to clarify further, 2 seperate queries could be used: 1.) SELECT SUM(value col) as SumV FROM Table WHERE(Clause)  2.) SELECT TOP(1) ReferenceNo AS LastRecorded FROM Table WHERE(Same Clause) ORDER BY ReferenceNo DESC.  What I need is to combine the 2 queries to get the result LastRecorded, SumV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like all of the items in the table need to be summed and returned with the max identifier.  Would this work for you?

```
Select Max(ID), Sum(Number) from TableName
```

ID would be your Unique Identifier column name.
Number would be your column name that holds the numbers.
TableName is the name of your table.

Comment: it's not all items in the table, but for some items in the table restricted by a where clause (which might be quite a long one)  The scenario actually relates to a fairly sizeable accounts package, so I ned to get aggreagate totals, but also to get the relevant "Unique Reference Number" as a cut off point.  It means that should the report be re-ran in the future, the simple addition of WHERE URN <= Recorded URN will recreate the same report excluding any further transactions recorded meeting the same criteria.

Comment: Not sure if using MAX might work though, I hadn't though of that, but I would imagine not as I would expect to get multiple rows back rather than just the sum of values meeting the relevant criteria and the last recorded reference number.